# Can i compare DateTimeFields with the tag "if"?

Tags: python, django

I have this issue and I can't see why it isn't working. I have this model:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[validate_content])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

And I have this "for" where I call the objects of the model:

```
 ...
{% for t in object_list %}     
    <tr>
    <td>{{ t.user }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.content }}</td>

    {% if t.updated == t.timestamp %}
    <td>Created: {{ t.updated| timesince }} </td>
    {% else %}
    <td>Updated: {{ t.updated| timesince }} </td>
    {% endif %}
    ...
```

I want to show the first message if the fields have the same content, which should be true if the object has just been created, but it shows the second message.

I have already checked in the admin panel the content of the fields and its the same in both, so I don't know what could be.

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting? Sharing your view might help as well

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the conditional is getting "false" even if the content of the fields are the same

Answer (score 1):

`auto_now=True` and `auto_now_add=True` each uses `datetime.now()` to obtain a timestamp, which always differ by a small fraction of a second because they are executed separately, so your the values of your `updated` and `timestamp` fields are never going to be equal.

You can instead get the timedelta between the two timestamps with `timesince` and if it's `0 minutes`, it can be practically considered as newly created:

```
{% if t.timestamp | timesince:t.updated == "0 minutes" %}
```

Comment: Hi, doesn't work:( i'm getting this error :

Django Version:  2.1 |
Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError |
Exception Value:  

Could not parse the remainder: '(t.updated' from '(t.updated'

Comment: I can't even use ".total_seconds()"

Comment: I see. Please try the solution in my updated answer then.